# Rails app - keeps trying to connect to localhost even though external database specified in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a rails app which i am trying to get up and running, i did not build this app, however due to extenuating circumstances it falls on me to do so.

I actually don't know anything about Ruby, as it is not a programming language i use on my day to day, so please bear with me

I have managed to configure an external database to work with this app. In my database.yml, i set out the environment variables and the rake db:create/migrate/seed command has successfully created the tables on the external database which i have verified.

Just for testing purposes both the development and production environments laid out in the database.yml use the external database variables so i can rule this out as a reason why it would not be working.

Database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: root

development:
  <<: *default
  database: production
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: 3306
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: 3306
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

As mentioned the rake command works fine, and i know it is accessing the external database because if i change the password to an incorrect one, rake gives me an error

When i run the rails server and try to access the api, i get the below error, at first it was cannot access mysql at 127.0.0.1 which i thought was odd because it was supposed to be acessing an external database, not the localhost, then i installed mysql on the same machine, and then i got password incorrect error, which obviously means that it is trying to access a local instance of mysql and not an external one. I changed the root password to match, and now i get the below when i access the api link:

(i've obfuscated the name of the api)

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError

Unknown database 'production'
Rails.root: /var/www/html/****-api

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `rescue in mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:10:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.2) lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'
appoptics_apm (4.4.0) lib/appoptics_apm/inst/rack.rb:136:in `metrics_sampling_call'
appoptics_apm (4.4.0) lib/appoptics_apm/inst/rack.rb:40:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
Request
Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, br"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "*****"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response
Headers:

None
```

Any ideas? I have tried everything i can think of, i have no idea why it is not picking up connection details from database.yml

Comment: How are you starting the application? It's likely being started in the "development" and not the "production" environment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i actually found out the reason for this particular issue, there was a pre-existing bash script i was using to restart the rails server, which i thought was fully restarting the server because it gave me the rails "starting server in production/development on localhost" message, but it actually wasn't, the below worked for me in fully restarting the server and clearing that error:
 lsof -wni tcp:3000
then running:
 kill -9 PID
where PID is the PID number on the table that appears after the first command
following that rails s -d restarts it correctly!